# Implementing Simpler Version of Google CoinDICE Algorithm for Off-Policy Confidence Interval Estimation in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning, evaluation, policy, confidence-interval

I am trying to implement an easily understandable version of the CoinDICE Algorithm from the Google DeepMind Paper [CoinDICE: Off-Policy Confidence Interval Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11652), so the Reinforcement Learning community can use it easily for their own applications.
Since the theory behind the algorithm is complicated and the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/google-research/dice_rl) has code which is hard to understand and does not connect well to the theory in the paper, I think that a lot of people would benefit from this.

I have already implemented everything one would need theoretically and reviewed the code with some of my peers.
Nevertheless, there still seems to be a problem with generating the correct results.
I will only describe my problem here without explaining about the CoinDICE-Paper above.

As my application I chose the `CartPole-v1`-environment and trained behavior and evaluation policies with the `A2C`-algorithm from `stable_baselines3` for 5000 and 10000 steps respectively.

```
import gymnasium as gym
from stable_baselines3 import A2C
from cv2 import destroyAllWindows

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1", render_mode="rgb_array")
models = {key: A2C("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=0) for key in ["b", "e"]}
models["b"].learn(total_timesteps=5_000)
models["e"].learn(total_timesteps=10_000)
vec_env = models["b"].get_env()
```

Their policy values should lie around 70-100.
However, my CoinDICE class yields an upper bound on the policy values which are far below what I would expect.
Each time a batch gets processed, the following stats are recorded:

- `L`: the approximation of the upper bound of the policy value,
- `grads_Q`: the length of the gradient of L with respect to the Q-network,
- `grads_zeta`: the same as grad_Q just with the zeta-network,
- `fun`: the error between the KL-divergence and its required bound,
- `D`: the KL-divergence,
- `lamda`: the Lagrange multiplier to bound the KL-divergence (lambda is a Python key word),
- `ell_mean` & `ell_std`: the mean and standard deviation of the sample of the random vector ell from the paper,
- `w_mean` & `w_std`: the mean and standard deviation of the output of (37) from the paper for w;

Using a function `plot_stats(stats_upper, decimals=4)`, I arrive at the following plot. (`stats_upper` gets calculated below.)

[stats over each processed batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTR0p.png)

I divided my code into a `SamplerCartpole`- and `CoinDICE`-class, whose instantiations you can find in the following two blocks of code.

```
gamma = 0.99
T = float("inf")

n_batches = 256
batch_size = 128

sampler = SamplerCartpole(vec_env, models, gamma, T, n_batches, batch_size)
```

```
input_shapes = {"s": (4,), "a": (1,)}
Q_net    = get_model(input_shapes)
zeta_net = get_model(input_shapes, last_activation="softplus")

lr = 0.0001
Q_opt = Adam(learning_rate=lr)
zeta_opt = Adam(learning_rate=lr)

alpha = 0.05
n_epochs = 8

lamda_init = 1

coindice = CoinDICE(sampler, alpha, n_epochs, Q_net, Q_opt, zeta_net, zeta_opt, lamda_init)
L, stats_upper = coindice.upper(record_stats=True)
```

Since sampling is specific to the environment and policy format, I have a general `Sampler`-class, which gets inherited by the more specific `SamplerCartpole`.

```
class Sampler:
    """
    connects the environment (MDP) and model(s) (policies) to the algorithm
    """

    def __init__(self, env, models, gamma, T, n_batches, batch_size):

        self.env = env
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.T = T

        self.n_batches = n_batches
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.models = models

        self.i_batch = 0
        self.get_batches()

    def preprocess_state(self, s):
        raise NotImplementedError("method must be overwritten")

    def preprocess_action(self, a):
        raise NotImplementedError("method must be overwritten")

    def preprocess_reward(self, r):
        raise NotImplementedError("method must be overwritten")

    def get_trajectory(self):

        states = []
        actions = []
        rewards = []

        s = self.env.reset()
        s = self.preprocess_state(s)
        states.append(s)

        done = False
        t = 0
        while not done and t < self.T:

            a = self.get_action(s)
            s, r, done, _ = self.env.step(a)

            a = self.preprocess_action(a)
            s = self.preprocess_state(s)
            r = self.preprocess_reward(r)

            actions.append(a)
            states.append(s)
            rewards.append(r)

            t += 1

        length = t
        return states, actions, rewards, length

    def get_batches(self):
        
        trajectories = []
        lengths = []
        for _ in tqdm(range(self.batch_size), desc="getting trajectories"):
            states, actions, rewards, length = self.get_trajectory()
            trajectories.append([states, actions, rewards])
            lengths.append(length)

        self.batches = [{"s_0": [], "s": [], "a": [], "r": [], "s_prime": []} for _ in range(self.n_batches)]

        for batch in self.batches:

            for trajectory, length in zip(trajectories, lengths):

                states, actions, rewards = trajectory

                i = np.random.randint(1, length-1)

                keys = ["s_0", "s", "a", "r", "s_prime"]
                values = [states[0], states[i], actions[i], rewards[i], states[i+1]]

                for key, value in zip(keys, values):
                    batch[key].append(value)

            for key, value in batch.items():
                batch[key] = tf.concat(value, axis=0)

    def get_batch(self):

        batch = self.batches[self.i_batch]

        self.i_batch += 1
        self.i_batch %= self.n_batches

        return batch["s_0"], batch["s"], batch["a"], batch["r"], batch["s_prime"]

    @property
    def action_space(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("method must be overwritten")

    def get_probabilities(self, s):
        raise NotImplementedError("method must be overwritten")

    def get_action(self, s):
        raise NotImplementedError("method must be overwritten")
```

```
from sampling import Sampler

class SamplerCartpole(Sampler):

    def preprocess_state(self, s):
        s = tf.convert_to_tensor(s)
        s = tf.squeeze(s)
        s = tf.expand_dims(s, axis=0)
        return s

    def preprocess_action(self, a):
        a = int(a)
        a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
        a = tf.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
        a = tf.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
        return a

    def preprocess_reward(self, r):
        r = float(r)
        r = tf.convert_to_tensor(r)
        r = tf.expand_dims(r, axis=0)
        r = tf.cast(r, dtype=tf.float32)
        return r

    @property
    def action_space(self):
        return [tf.convert_to_tensor([i]) for i in range(1)]

    def get_probabilities(self, s):

        s = s.numpy()

        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/70012691/16192280
        s = obs_as_tensor(s, self.models["e"].policy.device)
        p = self.models["e"].policy.get_distribution(s).distribution.probs.detach().numpy()

        p = np.squeeze(p).T

        return p

    def get_action(self, s):
        a, _ = self.models["b"].predict(s, deterministic=True)
        return a
```

Finally, the `CoinDICE`-class contains the algorithm itself, which is based on Algorithm 1 from the source paper.
Also, the `get_model`-function builds the two networks necessary for the algorithm to work.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import chi2
from scipy.optimize import minimize

from tqdm import tqdm

from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Concatenate

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

def get_model(input_shapes, last_activation="linear"):
    """
    input_shapes ... dict with keys "s" and "a" and values as input shape tuples for states and actions respectively
    """

    s_in  = Input(shape=input_shapes["s"])
    s_out = Dense(16,  activation="sigmoid")(s_in)

    a_in  = Input(shape=input_shapes["a"])
    a_out = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(a_in)

    s_a_in  = Concatenate()([s_out, a_out])
    x       = Dense(16, activation="relu")(s_a_in)
    # x       = Dropout(0.1)(x)
    # x       = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
    x       = Dropout(0.1)(x)
    x       = Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
    x       = Dropout(0.1)(x)
    s_a_out = Dense(1, activation=last_activation)(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[s_in, a_in], outputs=s_a_out)
    model.compile()
    return model

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

class CoinDICE:

    def __init__(self, sampler, alpha, n_epochs, Q_net, Q_opt, zeta_net, zeta_opt, lamda_init):

        """
        sampler : samples data from environment according to behavior policy \n
        policy_wrapper : for getting expected network output for state-action values for fixed state over actions \n
        gamma : discount factor \n
        alpha : 1 - alpha is the conficence \n
        n_epochs : # epochs \n
        Q_net : neural network for Q (see pseudocode) \n
        Q_opt : optimizer for Q_net (see pseudocode) \n
        zeta_net : neural network for zeta (see pseudocode), output should be >= 0 \n
        zeta_opt : optimizer for zeta_net (see pseudocode) \n
        eta : learning rate \n
        """

        self.sampler = sampler

        self.alpha = alpha
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs

        # set divergence limit
        self.xi = 1/2 * chi2.ppf(1-self.alpha, df=1)

        self.Q_net = Q_net
        self.Q_opt = Q_opt
        self.zeta_net = zeta_net
        self.zeta_opt = zeta_opt

        assert lamda_init > 0
        self.lamda_init = lamda_init

    @property
    def gamma(self):
        return self.sampler.gamma

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.sampler.batch_size

    @property
    def D_bound(self):
        return self.xi / self.n

    @property
    def n_batches(self):
        return self.sampler.n_batches

    @property
    def action_space(self):
        return self.sampler.action_space
    
    def get_probabilities(self, s):
        return self.sampler.get_probabilities(s)

    def get_value(self, net, s, a=None):

        if a is None: # take expectation over a

            actions = self.action_space
            probabilities = self.get_probabilities(s)

            expected_value = tf.zeros(len(s))
            for a, p in zip(actions, probabilities):
                a = tf.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
                a = tf.tile(a, [len(s), 1])
                expected_value += tf.squeeze(net([s, a])) * p

            return expected_value

        else:
            return tf.squeeze(net([s, a]))

    def conficence_bound(self, sign, record_stats=False):

        lamda = self.lamda_init

        Q_net = tf.keras.models.clone_model(self.Q_net)
        Q_opt = tf.keras.models.clone_model(self.Q_opt)
        zeta_net = tf.keras.models.clone_model(self.zeta_net)
        zeta_opt = tf.keras.models.clone_model(self.zeta_opt)

        w = tf.ones(self.n) / self.n

        stat_names = ["L", "D", "lamda", "fun", "grads_Q", "grads_zeta"] + ["w_mean", "w_std", "ell_mean", "ell_std"]
        stats = {stat_name: np.zeros([self.n_epochs, self.n_batches]) for stat_name in stat_names}

        for i_epoch in range(self.n_epochs):
            pbar = tqdm(range(self.n_batches), desc=f"epoch {i_epoch+1}/{self.n_epochs}")
            for i_batch in pbar:

                # Sample from target policy a_0^(j) ~ pi(s_0^(j)), a_prime^(j) ~ pi(s_prime^(j)) for j = 1, ..., n.
                s_0, s, a, r, s_prime = self.sampler.get_batch()

                # ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

                # Compute loss terms:
                # ell^(j) := (1 - gamma) Q_{theta_1}(s_0^(j), a_0^(j)) + zeta_{theta_2}(s^(j), a^(j)) * (-Q_{theta_1}(s^(j), a^(j)) + r^(j) + gamma Q_{theta_1}(s_prime^(j), a_prime^(j)))
                with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False, persistent=True) as tape:

                    tape.watch(Q_net.trainable_weights)
                    tape.watch(zeta_net.trainable_weights)

                    Q_0     = self.get_value(Q_net, s_0)
                    Q       = self.get_value(Q_net, s, a)
                    Q_prime = self.get_value(Q_net, s_prime)
                    zeta    = self.get_value(zeta_net, s, a)

                    A = (1 - self.gamma) * Q_0
                    B = zeta * (r + self.gamma * Q_prime - Q)
                    ell = A + B

                    stats["ell_mean"][i_epoch, i_batch] = np.mean(ell)
                    stats["ell_std"][i_epoch, i_batch] = np.std(ell)

                    # Compute loss L := sum_{j=1}^n w^(j) * ell^(j)
                    L = tf.reduce_sum(ell * w, axis=0)
                    stats["L"][i_epoch, i_batch] = float(L)

                    loss_Q = L
                    loss_zeta = -tf.reduce_sum(B * w, axis=0) # -L

                # ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

                # Update (theta_1, theta_2) <- OPT_theta(L, theta_1, theta_2)

                for loss, net, opt, key in zip([loss_Q, loss_zeta], [Q_net, zeta_net], [Q_opt, zeta_opt], ["grads_Q", "grads_zeta"]):

                    grads = tape.gradient(loss, net.trainable_weights)
                    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, net.trainable_weights))

                    stats[key][i_epoch, i_batch] = tf.norm([tf.norm(grad) for grad in grads])

                del tape

                # ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

                # Update (w, lamda) by (37)

                def get_w(lamda):
                    w = tf.math.exp(ell / lamda)
                    w /= tf.reduce_sum(w, axis=0)
                    return w

                def get_D(w):
                    # D = tf.reduce_sum(w * tf.math.log(w), axis=0) # paper
                    D = tf.reduce_sum(w * tf.math.log(w * self.n), axis=0) # mine
                    D = float(D)
                    return D

                def fun(x):
                    w = get_w(x)
                    D = get_D(w)
                    error = abs(D - self.D_bound)
                    return error

                # x0 = lamda
                # solution = minimize(fun=fun, x0=x0, bounds=[(0, None)])#, options={"maxiter": 100}, method="BFGS")
                # lamda = float(solution["x"])
                # assert abs(lamda) > 1e-9

                lamdas = np.linspace(max(lamda-1, 0.1), lamda+1, 100)
                funs = [fun(lamda) for lamda in lamdas]
                i = np.nanargmin(funs)
                lamda = lamdas[i]
                w = get_w(lamda)

                # print(f"{i=}; {lamda=}")
                # if i_batch % 10 == 0:
                #     plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
                #     plt.plot(lamdas, funs)
                #     plt.axvline(lamda, linestyle=":", color="black")
                #     # d = 0.1
                #     # plt.xlim([lamda-d, lamda+d])
                #     plt.show()

                stats["w_mean"][i_epoch, i_batch] = np.mean(w)
                stats["w_std"][i_epoch, i_batch] = np.std(w)

                stats["lamda"][i_epoch, i_batch] = lamda
                stats["D"][i_epoch, i_batch] = get_D(w)
                stats["fun"][i_epoch, i_batch] = fun(lamda)

                # ---------------------------------------------------------------- #

                pbar.set_postfix({key: stat[i_epoch, i_batch] for key, stat in stats.items()})

        bound = L / (1 - self.gamma)
        return (bound, stats) if record_stats else bound

    def upper(self, record_stats=None):
        sign = 1
        return self.conficence_bound(sign, record_stats)

    def lower(self, record_stats=None):
        raise NotImplementedError
        sign = -1
        return self.conficence_bound(sign, record_stats)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------- #
```